# Repeating a template in smarty ( no logic in template)

Tags: php, smarty

I dont want to write my loop in my tpl file.

I want to do something like this

```
foreach($arr as $val=>$key){
   $tpl->push($val); //not assign
}
//
$tpl->repeatDisplay('my.tpl');
```

or something like this

```
$tpl->repeatFor("mytile",$arr);
$tpl->repeatDisplay('my.tpl');
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need or what you want to achieve or why you can't loop inside a tpl file

Comment: You probably have read somewhere that it is bad practice to put program logic in your template files. However having a simple loop in the template file has nothing to do with program logic, the loop is purely about displaying the values, so there is nothing wrong with using a loop in templates.

Comment: I know how to loop in tpl file, I want use php to decide if i want to loop or not. nothing logical or looping in tpl

Comment: @pep but a loop is not always that simple, what if there are number of conditions if else and so on inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont thias there is any other way around this, so try

```
foreach($arr as $val=>$key){
   $tpl->assign('var',$val);
   $tpl->display('my.tpl'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is simple using fetch instead of display :

```
$output = '';
foreach($arr as $val=>$key){
   $tpl->assign('var',$val);
   $output .= $tpl->fetch('my.tpl'); 
}

echo $output;
```

But if you want to use it only to display simple variable in my.tpl it doesn't make much sense as you can read in comments. Using loops in templates is simple fine is you use it for displaying data.